# 22.0.1/aapt'' finished with > non-zero exit value 132 [With android sizes]

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

Using gradle build I got this message.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     '/home/*user*/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 132

This is vague and adding --info or --debug to the gradle command, did not indicate anything. By process of elimination I could reproduce the error if I was using a physical dimension.

```
android:textSize="10dp"
```

It didn't have to be textSize any size property causes a problem, [sp, dp, mm, in...]. Also defining a **dimen** gave the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by using a different version of android build tools, specifically aapt.

I tried a couple of different versions of aapt

> sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt v
>
> gives the version

- build tools 23.0.2 > Android Asset Packaging Tool, v0.2-2355899
- build tools 22.0.1 > Android Asset Packaging Tool, v0.2-1793126
- build tools 19.0.0 > Android Asset Packaging Tool, v0.2

Only 22.0.1, v0.2-1793126 gave a problem. So I am using a newer one.